# Issue in deployment of cord app

Tags: corda

I checked https://docs.corda.net/deploying-a-node.html for deploying in windows server. I can see deploying nodes using NSSM Manager.

1. When I deploy nodes, how it will access my application which is placed as a jar under /opt/corda /CordaApp.jar
2. Also, When I run nssm.bat file under each nodes, my cmd is going on running with the first cmd and not stopping. Nothing proceed after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in the docs. Where it says:

> 2. Create a directory called plugins in /opt/corda and save your CorDapp jar file to it. Alternatively, download one of our sample CorDapps to the plugins directory

It should read instead:

> 2. Create a directory called plugins in C:\Corda\ and save your CorDapp jar file to it. Alternatively, download one of our sample CorDapps to the plugins directory

This was fixed by the following PR: https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/2607.